# Overlay the average trend on group by trends using Proc sgplot

Tags: sas, visualization

I want to create a line graph that includes the overall trend of a disease rate and the specific trends for males and females. I use the following code for to create the group by trends. How to add he average trend to this line graph. Thanks for your help.

```
proc sgplot data=have ;
vline year/response=disease_rate group=sex stat=mean datalabel=disease_rate  ;
yaxis values=(0,1)  label="Percentage";
run;
```

Comment: I think if you want different summary levels on your graph you need to pre-summarize your graph data unfortunately.  Is disease_rate a 0/1 variable?

Comment: The disease variable is binary, but the disease_rate is percentage, a number between zero and one. What would be the best way to pre-summarize the graph data? Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer below, hopefully you can adjust it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `series` instead of `vline` so that you can overlay a regression on top of it to get an average trend line. For example:

```
proc sql;
    create table have as
        select date
             , region
             , sum(sale) as sale
        from sashelp.pricedata
        group by region, date
        order by region, date
    ;
quit;

proc sgplot data=have;
    series x=date y=sale / group=region;
    reg    x=date y=sale / group=region;
    xaxis fitpolicy=rotatethin;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of summarizing it and then displaying it on the graph. There are more than one way to do this though, this is just one.

```
data have;
set sashelp.heart(in=a);
year=round(2021-ageAtStart, 10);
disease_rate= status="Dead";
run;

proc means data=have mean noprint;
class sex year;
types sex sex*year;
var disease_rate;
output out=summary_stats mean=average_value;
run;

proc sort data=summary_stats;
by sex year;
run;


data graph_data;
merge summary_stats(where=(_type_=2) rename=average_value=mean_sex_year)
      summary_stats(where=(_type_=3) rename=average_value = mean_sex);
by sex;
format mean_sex: percent12.1;
run;



proc sgplot data=graph_data ;
*where year > 1990;
vline year/response=mean_sex_year group=sex stat=mean datalabel=mean_sex_year  ;
vline year/response=mean_sex group=sex stat=mean datalabel=mean_sex  ;

run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This gives me a plot with a reference line for each sex, separately. But, what I want is to add a middle trend line that shows the overall trend to the specific sex trends. Something like                                                                                     ```vline year/response=disease_rate stat=mean datalabel=disease_rate  ;```, which is a vline without group=sex to be added to the code. Basically, I'd like to have the overall trend and sex trends all in one plot.

Comment: Change the TYPES statements in the PROC MEANS to what levels/groupings you want and then the `_TYPE_` in the data step/merge to get the value overall then. I don't think there's an easy way to have that done overall in the SGPLOT if that's what you're looking for. I don't think you can easily do different levels in the statements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Reeza!